# Passing a list into a two-dimensional array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm trying to write a method that uses a list I've created to populate a two-dimensional array. Please forgive me, as this is obviously very basic Java, and I'm quite new. Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MagicSquare 
{
static final int rows = 4;
static final int columns = 4;
static final int listSize = 16;
static int row, col;
static Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);

public static void createArithmeticSeq(int [] list)
{   
    int first; 
    int diff;
    //prompt user for first and diff
    System.out.println("Enter first and diff : ");
    first = console.nextInt();
    diff  = console.nextInt();
    //process to create list of 16 elements 
    for (int i=0; i<listSize; i++)
    {
        list[i]=first+i*diff;
    }
}
//this is where I'm having trouble
public static void matricize (int [] list, int [][] matrix)
{
//loop through each row
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
    {
    //loop through each column
        for (col=0; col<matrix[row].length; col++)
        {
        //populate matrix with values from list

                matrix[row][col]=**????**;
        }
    }
}
public static void printMatrix(int [][] matrix)
{

    for (row=0; row < matrix.length; row++)
    {
        for (col=0; col < matrix[row].length; col++)
            System.out.printf("%2d" + " ", matrix[row][col]);

        System.out.println();
    }
    //ToDo
}

public static void reverseDiagonal(int [] [] matrix)
{
    //ToDo
}

public static void magicCheck(int [] list, int [] [] matrix)
{
    //ToDo
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    int [] list = new int [listSize];
    int [] [] matrix = new int [rows] [columns];
    createArithmeticSeq (list);
    matricize(list, matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    reverseDiagonal(matrix);
    printMatrix(matrix);
    magicCheck(list, matrix);   
}

}
```

Please ignore the methods I haven't gotten to yet, obviously. I just need to figure this one out first.

Comment: What is your problem exactly?

Comment: I'm not sure how to pass the integers from list[] into the matrix[][].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the list stores the matrix elements in a linear array and you want to reorganize the data as a matrix in your `matricize` method.

The easiest thing is to keep a separate index for the list and increment it as you populate the matrix. If the list stores the matrix elements in row-major order, you can do this:

```
public static void matricize (int [] list, int [][] matrix)
{
    int listIndex = 0;
    //loop through each row
    for (row=0; row<matrix.length; row++)
    {
        //loop through each column
        for (col=0; col<matrix[row].length; col++)
        {
            //populate matrix with values from list
            matrix[row][col] = list[listIndex++];
        }
    }
}
```

If the list is in column-major order, simply reverse the order in which the loops are nested.

Comment: Thanks. I've rewritten matricize the way you've suggested. I'm still running into an issue, however, as when I run the program I end up not with a [4][4] matrix, but a [8][4] matrix, and each element is the same, e.g. if first=21 and diff=5, every element is 96.

Comment: Let me clarify a bit: In the method createArithmeticSeq, a 16-element list is created by selecting a first integer (first), then selecting a number by which to increment this by (diff). The method loops through to create the list. This is the list I would like to use to create a [4][4] matrix.

Comment: Actually, I've just figured it out. I had to change "listIndex" to i, since I used the variable i in the first method, createArithmeticSeq. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @user2469532 - I'm glad it worked out. Sorry for being afk for 20 minutes.